# Can't pass file name as an argument to my python script

Tags: python, windows, contextmenu

I can't pass file name as an argument to my python script from context menu. Instead it passes only path to a folder where I ran my script

I have spent several days without any success trying to figure out.

1. I have created batch file with full path to python.exe and second path to the script i'd like to run

   ```
   "C:\Users\scurs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\TestScripts\PythScripts\Renamer\BatTest.py"
   pause
   ```

   https://ibb.co/X8Pq4jH
2. Using Defaults Program Editor I have added my .bat file to a context menu
   [.bat file full path with "%1"]  https://ibb.co/wSLQZjS
3. In the random directory after right click on the file I chose my bat script from the context menu
   [right click on the selected file and running my script from context menu] 
   https://ibb.co/ZWGLBJT
4. CMD window opens displaying only full path of directory I run my script from 
   [cmd window with folder path only]  https://ibb.co/NnX6yBG

   ```
   import sys    
   file ='%s' %sys.argv[0]  
   print(file)
   ```

I am trying to write a script which will be replacing selected picture(or multiple pictures) with blank (just black canvas) but keeping the original name.

I want my script to be able to copy the name of selected file, then copy "blank" image from script folder and rename as selected file and replace the original.

Can't make my script read file names.

I am half way trough my first python book, hence lacking knowledge.

Kind Regards

Victor

Comment: you're not passing any args. *pause* is a command. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name.

Comment: if first batch you would have to use `%1` to run script with argument -  `python.exe script.py %1` And in Python script you should have it as `sys.argv[1]`. But it is good to check `if len(sys.argv) > 1:` before you get `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Thank you gentleman, @CristiFati, so shall I delete "pause" or replace it with something else?

Comment: Thank you very much guys! all sorted!